# KNPPaginatorBundle Featured Results on First Page

Tags: symfony, knppaginator

Let's say I have an online shop with 100 items and using KNPPaginatorBundle to handle the paginator with 10 items per page and 5 of the 100 items are featured items. Each item have a boolean field 'featured' that tells if it should be before the non-featured items or not. Is there any way to handle this with the bundle?

At the moment I have one array with the 5 featured items and another with the 100 unfeatured and I iterate over the first one normally and over the second one using the bundle, but that approach gives me 15 results at the first page. So it would be ideal if I can tell the bundle to return 5 items on page 1 and 10 on the following 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way it to create a Query with 'featured' items first. (order by?).

If, for some reason you are not able to create such query, but you have items, you can pass collection to paginate directly:

```
$collection = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($featured);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $collection->add($item);
}

$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $collection,
    $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
    10/*limit per page*/
);
```

Comment: That will do the trick! I thought about orderBy, but probably there would be the case I have 20 featured items, but anyways have to show just 5 in front and the rest of them as regular ones. Thanks!